# SXA theme without using node-sass

Tags: sxa

I created a new SXA theme in Sitecore 10.2.0 and it is bringing in `"@sxa/celt": "^10.2.2"` which in turn brings in node-sass.
This package is deprecated and I want to use dart-sass instead, however when building the theme it still uses `node-sass` even though I have `sass` installed. This is a problem for example if trying to use the new sass:math library.

Any ideas how to force it to use sass instead of node-sass?

Comment: From the one side, @sxa/celt is just a "boilerplate" for creating the SXA theme. On the other side, it uses a lot(especially tasks) of @sxa/celt itself... `node-sass` dependency comes from `gulp-sass`. It means that you will need to override JS files from NPM packages, which is not cool and not convenient. But, it is possible, e.g. I did a similar thing for SXA source map files: https://exdst.com/posts/sitecore-sxa-css-source-map.

Good thing is that @sxa/celt 10.2.2 > gulp-sass@^5.0.0 > gulp-sass has support of `dart-sass`. It means that it should be just a few lines of changes.

Comment: For now I have imported sxa/celt's files and modified as it is directly importing node-sass.